# Parent div shrinking smaller than width of child table

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-float, overflow

I have a wrapper `div` with only a fixed height. There are two child `div`s, both of which are floated to be horizontal. The right-hand child `div` contains a table. I expect the right-hand `div` to shrink to the width of the child table. Instead, in cases in which vertical content overflows, the `div` shrinks to **smaller** than the `table` (in Firefox and Chrome on Windows; not on Mac b/c the scrollbars are overlaid), which results in horizontal scrollbar appearing. It appears the overflow width is about the same as the scrollbar width, and there is no overflow if the table does not stretch beyond the parent height. The `table` content is dynamically loaded, so it will change, which is why I want the parent `.selector-chapter` to stretch in width to match without horizontal scrolling.

You can look at the real thing [here](http://bible.preahkumpii.com/beta/). Click the book, then any text in the left pane that causes the right pane to overflow (the first line will work).

I have tried everything I can find even closely related on Stack Overflow, including `table-layout: fixed` and parent `display: table`.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<div class='selector'>
    <div class='selector-book'>
        <ul>...</ul>
    </div>
    <div class='selector-chapter'>
        <table>
            <tr><td>foobar</td><td>foobar</td><td>foobar</td></tr>
            <tr><td>foobar</td><td>foobar</td><td>foobar</td></tr>
            <tr><td>foobar</td><td>foobar</td><td>foobar</td></tr>
            ...
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

.selector {
    position: fixed;
    top: 55px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 500px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px;
}
.selector-book,
.selector-chapter {
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.selector-book ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.selector-book li {
    padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 0;
}
.selector-book {
    float: left;  
}
.selector-chapter {
    float: right;
}
.selector-chapter table td {
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done debugging.. can you apply following changes to your code.

```
.selector { width: auto; display table;}
```

please check selector is getting width through JS i think

```
.selector-book, .selector-chapter {display:table-cell;vertical-align:top;}
```

remove float of above divs

and den apply overflow to the divs ul and div inside. .selector-book, .selector-chapter

Comment: I have not been able to get this to work. The last line of your answer is ambiguous. Apply overflow to which divs?

Comment: selector-book, .selector-chapter..

take a div inside above div's and add overflow:auto to it. give fixed height to this divs.

can you provide me fiddle of the code so I can correct you answer

Comment: I surrounded the `.selector-book, .selector-chapter` divs with another div, like I think you are saying. Doing it this way requires that a fixed height be given to the divs, which is not what I want. The height is determined by the height of the `.selector` div. Besides, this does not solve my original problem, the parent div smaller than child table.